# What should be the Loss Function for Image Reconstruction while using UNET architecture using Keras/Tensorflow 2?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I am building and testing a new approach for Image Reconstruction for a task.  I used something like [Xception Based UNET](https://keras.io/examples/vision/oxford_pets_image_segmentation/). But instead of comparing pixels for 3 classes Black, White, Grey; I want to reconstruct the full image as it is so that my Model can learn something. I used data Generator to Black and White images as:

```
train = gen.flow_from_directory(dir,color_mode='grayscale',class_mode='input',batch_size=batch_size,target_size=(w,h),seed=SEED,subset='training')
```

and I used the last 2 lines of the code as:

```
outputs = layers.Conv2D(1, 1, activation = 'sigmoid')(x) # Last Layer is 1x1 Conv 
# Sigmoid will give 0-1 values per pixel and we'll calculate RMSE
model = Model(inputs, outputs)
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mse',metrics=[keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError()])
```

For a different model approach, I tried, `RMSE` with `r_squared` as a metric as:

```
def rmse(y_true, y_pred):
        return K.sqrt(K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true)))


def r_squared(y_true, y_pred):
    SS_res =  K.sum(K.square( y_true-y_pred ))
    SS_tot = K.sum(K.square( y_true - K.mean(y_true) ) )
    return ( 1 - SS_res/(SS_tot + K.epsilon()) )

model =model.compile('adam',loss=rmse, metrics=[r_squared])
```

I want to know if there is any other metric and/or loss given by Keras or Tensorflow for this type of problems. I am using `Grayscale` images and trying to force the Latent space to learn something meaningful about the images.

Answer (score 1):

from what I understand you are working on a **auto-encoding** task, trying to compress then reconstruct the intput.

From my experience the the loss used is often one of these two:

- `MSE`, has the advantage that the optimal solution for your model is to predict the mean of the potential values. For example if your model thinks that a certain pixel has a value of 0 with probability 0.3, and 1 with probability 0.7, the best solution for your model is to predict `0.7 = 0.3*0 + 0.7*1`.
- `MAE`, Mean absolute error, also known as L1. The advantage of `MAE` is that the best solution for your model is to predict the median. In the precedent example, the median would be 1. Sometimes `MEA` yields better example than `MSE`.

A more extreme example, is that if you are working on a self driving car, and the car has to decide going left or right, `MSE` will go in the middle, while `MAE` will pick a side.

You can compute the `MAE` this way:

```
mae = tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(prediction - taget))
```

`RMSE` should yield similar results to `MSE`. The square root, is probably not very useful.

Comment: That seems to be correct, since this Tensorflow [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/autoencoder) on autoencoders uses `"mae"` and `"mse"`